# Why is using /tmp/ more popular and recommended than using /dev/shm?

Tags: linux, tmp

From my own experience, i noticed that most people use /tmp/ for temp files or to save on disk write, but i don't often see anyone recommending or even using /dev/shm instead.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/dev/shm` is intended to be used for shared memory segments that live in the file system.  There are two types of shared memory: SysV shared memory and POSIX shared memory.  POSIX shared memory uses named segments created via `shm_open`, and these typically live in the file system under `/dev/shm`, which is usually a tmpfs.  `/dev/shm` is usually mounted `nosuid` and `noexec`.

`/tmp` is intended to be used for temporary files.  On some systems, it is a tmpfs, but on many systems it is backed by disk.  On many systems, it is possible to run programs from `/tmp` because it is not marked `noexec`.  The system administrator may have sized it appropriately (either larger or smaller) to fit the needs of the particular system.

`/var/tmp` is like `/tmp`, but the latter is usually cleared on boot while the former is not.  The latter should be used in most cases, but if a temporary file needs to persist for a longer period of time, `/var/tmp` can be used.

So there's no explicit reason why you physically cannot use `/dev/shm` for temporary files, but it isn't a typical use case or its intended purpose, and people won't expect it.  If your goal is to write code that is easy to maintain and that works optimally across a variety of systems, it's best to follow the conventions unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise.

Comment: What OSes clear `/tmp` on boot? I am only used to CentOS / RHEL OSes lately which do not do this. I believe they age files out over time.

Comment: @cutrightjm Most Unices clear `/tmp` on boot.

Comment: yeah, following good coding practice i guess would be one of the reason for this trend, though i do wonder about the performance differences between /dev/shm and /tmp/...guess it'll be for another post later on.

Comment: If `/tmp` is a tmpfs, then it performs identically.  The system administrator can configure that if temporary file speed is important to them.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly I don't know why (or if) `/tmp` is more popular than `/dev/shm`. I know why it should be more recommended.

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) defines the directory structure and directory contents in Linux distributions. It [specifies `/tmp`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s18.html):

> The `/tmp` directory must be made available for programs that require temporary files.

But it does not specify `/dev/shm`. Search for `shm` in the [text version](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.txt) to confirm this.

Comment: Interesting fact!